# How to get uppercase words in sentence using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get special words from script to search it in Wikipedia to get explanation.

**Input text:**
"Thai, or Central Thai, is a Tai language of the Kra–Dai language family spoken by the Central Thai people and a vast majority of Thai Chinese. It is the sole official language of Thailand. I want to... "

**The expect ouput:**
["Thai", "Central Thai", "Kra–Dai", "Thai Chinese", "Thailand"]

Then by uing the Wikipedia API I will get the definitions of the words above. I am using this regular expression:

```
[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]*)?
```

However when I try the result is:

["Thai", "Central Thai", "Kra", "Dai", "Thai Chinese", "Thailand", "I", "It"]

It is separating the words with that contains "-" and including the ones that start with upper after a dot "." and also is including "I" and "It".

How could I get all uppercase words except the uppercase word after "."

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: @Green绿色 I just edited the post with the regular expression I am using, is this one:
[code] [A-Z][-a-zA-Z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]*)? [/code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use word boundaries `\b`.

```js
let str = 'Thai, or Central Thai, is a Tai language of the Kra-Dai language family spoken by the Central Thai people and a vast majority of Thai Chinese. It is the sole official language of Thailand. I want to...';
let arr =[...str.matchAll( /\b[A-Z]\w{2,}-?(\s?\b[A-Z]\w*)?/g)].map(e=>e[0]);
console.log(arr);
```

> How could I get all uppercase words except the uppercase word after "."

But you can get special words at the start of a sentence too:
`Periplectic group consists of the group's last common ancestor and all its descendants`

Comment: It works for me! Thank you! yeah, I am trying to figure out how to identify special words at the start of sentence now

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me `(?!.\s)[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+|[–]+[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+)`

Comment: Thanks for answering, this worked for me also!